# AWS Elastic Beanstalk callbacks from Worker Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Elastic Beanstalk worker instance (node.js) that renders some PDF documents and drops them into a S3 bucket. When its done, it needs to signal back to the Web instance (node.js) that its done. What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking I could use a HTTP request to callback to the web instance. To do this I would pass a callback URL in the SQS message body along with the data.

Or, I could use a RDS table that both can read and write to. This does not seem as good since the Web instance would need to keep polling the DB to see when the record is marked as completed.

Thanks in Advance,

J.

Comment: Does every elastic beanstalk web instance need to be notified, or is it good enough if just one of them is notified?

Comment: Just the one the current user is connected to; the'll need to be able to download the PDFs once created.

Comment: How would the worker server know which web server the client is connected to? It sounds like you need to notify all web servers. I would have them all subscribe to an SNS topic, and have the worker server post notifications to SNS.

Comment: A web server should know its now address (CNAME or IP) so I was going to pass a callback URL in the SQS message body that the worker can use.

Comment: I ended up using SQS to communicate back to the Web instances that the job was finished. Seems to work well. No need for SNS; its a bit redundant in this situation.